# dataWithContentsOfURL error 256 in ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I have used the

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error]`

in my code on iOS 5 apps (using xcode 4.3)

Now I want to get data from the same URL but for ios 6 apps (using xcode 4.5) and it gives me the 256 error (read error (reason unknown))

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your url include the http://?

Comment: No it did not.. never did but as of today it always will, that was it. Thanks Abizern!

Comment: could you show content of URL, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments and it now seems that this was the answer.

the URL needs to be a properly formed URL with the proper http:// identifier.

Comment: Also for local files it needs `file://` prefix.