# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: stopped working in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, nsdata

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531558/datawithcontentsofurl-error-256-in-ios-6).

However, the accepted answer (and the only answer) does not solve my problem.

I have a "hybrid" iOS app containing among other things a UITabView with a set of UIWebViews showing some app content in HTML5 from a web server. Under the hood there is a little home-made cache engine that caches content in the background. This cache engine fills its data using this line

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:request.URL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

So far the app has worked perfectly without any problems, but in iOS 6, it is not working anymore. Using the debugger I have came to conclusion that it is the above line that is not working. When I step accross the above line it just cant load the page, and after a while I get an error 256. When I switch to iOS 5, it works perfectly.

I have printed the NSURL-object request.URL and it looks like it should and it does have the "http://"-part included, like this:

```
http://app.customername.com/.mvc/MobileApp/Index
```

I also tried loading a test page that is unrelated to the application website, a very simple html-page that I made myself, and also http://www.google.com

Both of them worked in iOS 5.1 but the same problem occurred with these pages in iOS 6.

I also tried using the method without the "Uncached" option like this, but still no luck:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:request.URL]
```

Has something changed in iOS 6 for the method data dataWithContentsOfURL: and has someone else seen this problem?

Comment: I use it fine in an app build with iOS 6.         NSString *urlString = imageURL;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if (!data) {
            NSLog(@"MAJOR ISSUE");
        }

Comment: It is strange indeed, it has to be some context thing, but I can't wrap my head around what it could be and why it's not working specifically in iOS6. The call is in a background thread inside the populateCachefor: method of my NSURLCache subclass.

Comment: having the same exact problem with the same exact line of code, also being called by a subclass of NSURLCache. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was having the same exact problem, and I don't know the exact cause.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the NSURLCache thread not playing nice with dataWithContentsOfURL. If anybody knows why please chime in.

Bottom line, I already had ASIHTTP in my project, so I replaced this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

With this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request startSynchronous];        
NSData *data = [request responseData];
```

And now all is well.

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved my friday =) Thousands of thanks to you!